# SpringBoot: Wrap the Controller Response into Another Object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Consider the below Controller method,

```
@GetMapping("/getdata")
public Data getDetails() {
                
    try {
        Data obj = template.getForObject("http://localhost:8090/details/get", Data.class);
        return obj; 

    } catch (Exception e) {
        .....
    }       
}
```

Let's say the response object for the above endpoint looks like,

```
data : {
 name : "ABCD",
 age  : "20"
}
```

Now what I am trying to achieve is to Wrap the entire response object under another object, so the final response should look like,

```
{
   status : "SOMETHING",
   response : {
     name : "ABCD",
     age  : "20"
   },
   extra : null
}
```

So the issue is, I don't want to create a function under each controller method to sent values to this Wrapper Object. My question is, Is there any possibility in Spring Framework that allows me to create a Global Wrapper function somewhere, and it will automatically pick it and wrap the response from the controller?

Comment: Moderate nitpick:  HTTP specifies status codes to indicate certain states (like 200 for success, 4xx or 5xx for failures); why do you want to re-wrap that in your response object which requires frameworks or API consumers to break convention?

Comment: @Makoto I know it's weird, but this is what I am asked to do. But true, it doesn't make any sense... Maybe some other functionalities will be added to this. But I just wanna know, is it possible?

Comment: Check this example, it sounds like what you are looking for: http://www.javabyexamples.com/quick-guide-to-responsebodyadvice-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement a `ResponseBodyAdvice` as a `@ControllerAdvice`. First, you need to have a model for your generic response.

```java
public class GenericResponse<T> {
    private String status;
    private String extra;
    private T response;
}
```

Then you need to implement the `ResponseBodyAdvice` itself:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomResponseBodyAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object response, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType,
                                  Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request,
                                  ServerHttpResponse response) {    
        GenericResponse<Object> genericResponse = new GenericResponse<>();
        output.setStatus("SOMETHING"); // I guess that you need some logic here
        output.setResponse(response);
        return genericResponse;
    }
}
```